# How to add 'details' row gorup in SSRS report design table report that was accidentally deleted?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I working SSRS report designer tutorial; while working on groups, I accidentally deleted 'details' row group and couldn't find a way to restore or add it. Please look to the screenshot to understand what I am referring to.

would anyone please help me find a solution!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add a row group with no grouping. There is nothing special about the default 'Details' rowgroup, other than it has no grouping specified.